# ARM Cortex-A8: How to measure cache utilization?

Tags: memory-management, arm, profiler, cpu-cache, cortex-a8

I have a Freescale's i.MX515EVK, an ARM Cortex-A8/Ubuntu platform with me, unfortunately the Linux kernel on the board is not supporting some of the well known profilers such as [Oprofiler](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) or [Zoom Profiler](http://www.rotateright.com/)*(Zoom supports ARM processors, but it internally, uses Oprofiler driver)* which give very detailed reports about the cache utilization.

Cortex-A8 has 32KB Instruction and Data caches and a 256KB L2 Cache. Currently when my image processing algorithm is running, I'm totally blind about their usage.

Are there any other methods, other than using profilers to find out cache hits and misses?

Comment: Have you had any luck with it since?

Answer (score 1):

Install Valgrind (it supports ARM nowdays) and use the cachegrind tool to check cache utilization. If you are running Ubuntu on the device, it should be as simple as `sudo apt-get install valgrind`. Valgrind can also help you simulate what would happen with different cache sizes.